# populating a java array with a variable

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to populate a java string array with a variable. the variable contains values which I am reading in from a text file. every time a new value is stored in the array the current value is replaced by the new value.

the code below is what i have tried so far.

```
int n = 0;

String var1 = value;

String array[] = {var1};

String [] array = new String[n];

    for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {

     array[n++] = value;

    }
```

Comment: Where is `value` defined? I presume the code you've shown us is from inside a loop, where you are reading different values into `value`? Also, your code example could never compile since you define `array` twice. Please show us your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Java has only fixed sized arrays; dynamically growing "arrays" are realized with [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i) {
    String s = "" + i;
    array.add(s);
}

for (String t : array) {
     System.out.println(t);
}

String seven = array.get(7);
int n = array.size();
if (array.isEmpty()) { ... }

// In Java 8:
array.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Using (fixed sized) arrays would be cumbersome:

```
String[] array = new String[];
String[] otherVar = array;
for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i) {
    String s = "" + i;
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, i + 1);
    array[i] = s;
}
```

Here on every step a new array is created, the content of the old array copied.
Also notice that `otherVar` keeps the initial empty array.

Note that `String[] a` is the same as `String a[]`. The latter is only for compatibility to C/C++, and is less readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will add a string indefinitely. When you read all the data from file you have to set `isFileNotEnded = false`

```
    boolean isFileNotEnded = true;
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<>;
    while (isFileNotEnded) {
        array.add("hello");
        //stop here the infinite loop
    }
```

Comment: i do not know how much data is in the text file

Comment: then you can't use arrays, but you have to use ArrayList